# making a cell mandatory in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue trying to make column C Mandatory based on an entry in column B below. I am not that experienced with VBA.

```
A                B                      C
Name          Password Needed (Y/N)   Validator
Joe Doe     
Mike Smith      
Fred Hammer
```

Comment: 1. SO is not a coding service - please provide what you've tried so far.
2. This is not really a question - please elaborate on the desired behavior.

Comment: Go for data validation instead of vba

Answer (score 0):

This is probably better handled with a formula. Put this in C2 -

```
=IF(B2 = "Yes",TRUE,FALSE)
```

hit enter.

Grab the little square mark on the bottom right corner of C2 with your mouse and drag it down to as many names you have in column A.  This will fill in those rows with the formula corrected for each row.  Type Yes in column B for anyone who needs to use a password.  And Column C will show True for anyone requiring a password.